# Grid View columns out of the blue

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

This is about GridView controls. I created one where I manually specified the columns (by coding), but when I run the project, I get more columns than specified in the code.

Here is the code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="cid" 
        onrowcancelingedit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
        onrowdeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing" 
        onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Category name" 
            SortExpression="name" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="description" HeaderText="Category description" 
            SortExpression="description" />

        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="cid" 
            DataNavigateUrlFormatString="AdminCategories.aspx?CategID={0}" 
            HeaderText="See categories" Text="See Categories" />

        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" EditText="Edit" HeaderText="Edit Categories"/>

        <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" HeaderText="Delete Categories"/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

As a result, when I run the project I get the following headers in the GridView:

Category name | Category description | See categories | Edit Categories | Delete Categories | **name | description**

7 columns in total. However, if you check the code, only the first 5 columns are inclued in the code. So **why do the last 2 columns appear and how can I delete them**?

Thank you!

Anna

Answer (score 2):

You should set the AutoGenerateColumns Property of the gridview to false , since you have not done that those two last columns are generated automatically !!!
 rewrite your code this way :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="cid"   
    onrowcancelingedit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"   
    onrowdeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing"   
    onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">  
<Columns>  
    <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Category name"   
        SortExpression="name" />  

    <asp:BoundField DataField="description" HeaderText="Category description"   
        SortExpression="description" />  

    <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="cid"   
        DataNavigateUrlFormatString="AdminCategories.aspx?CategID={0}"   
        HeaderText="See categories" Text="See Categories" />  

    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" EditText="Edit" HeaderText="Edit Categories"/>  

    <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" HeaderText="Delete Categories"/>  
</Columns>
```